# repeat runs of URI google.navigation fail

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, html, google-maps

I've been developing a small asp.net website in which I require to open the android (and iPhone) native map application with directions to a pre-specified address, to do this I'm using this link

```
    protected void anLogic()
      {
        string street = "my address here";
        string formattedstreet = street.Replace(" ", "+");
        string address = "google.navigation:q=" + formattedstreet;
        Label1.Text = address;
        Response.Redirect(address);

      }
```

However, if the user has already clicked the link before and pressed the return button on their phone and tries to reclick, or already has google maps open the button does nothing.
I have also tried the format:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?
api=1&destination=Pike+Place+Market+Seattle+WA&travelmode=bicycling">Text</a>
```

But I've had similar results.
Basically the only method I've found to get these to work again is for the user to completely close their mobile web browser and google maps and start from the beginning again, which is less than ideal.

Noticed that google uses intents on the google mobile site which does not share this issue: [image: googles version]

So I've been modifying my link to use intents rather than universal links:

```
<a href="intent://www.google.com.au/maps/dir//(ADDRESS+HERE)
#Intent;scheme=http;package=com.google.android.apps.maps;end"> test </a>
```

I've still had no luck, link still only works once, anyone know a method of overcoming this issue?

Edit: 16/10/20118 not solved yet, anyone looking over this, note the google reference documents from most useful to me to least:

https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents
and
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide
and
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters